# iOS Safari: Using deeplink, how I can prevent the opening app store when app is installed?

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, swift, deeplink

I am implementing the `deeplink` for `iOS app`, and its implemented, but the problem is when I clicked on `deeplink API` in iPhone, the app is opening but after the given time the app store page also gets open on the top of app.

Here what I am doing:

I have an node API for `deeplink` which is sending an HTML file name `send.html` who has some javascript code as:

**send.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="/deeplink-redirect.js"></script>
</head>

<body deeplink="iOS_DEEPLINK_URL" appstorelink="APP_STORE_LINK">

    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" />
    <br />
    <a href="APP_STORE_LINK">Download the app</a>
</body>

</html>
```

**deeplink-redirect.js**

```
window.onload = function () {
    window.location.href = document.body.getAttribute('deeplink');
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = document.body.getAttribute('appstorelink');
    }, 500)
}
```

**But what is going on:** When I clicked on `deeplink API` in iPhone, it sends the above HTML file in safari and the app URL `window.location.href = document.body.getAttribute('deeplink');` open the app but after 500ms code `document.body.getAttribute('appstorelink');` gets executed and its open the app store on the top of my app.

But If I increase the timeout from 500 to 4000 then its working fine and app store is not opening. But I want very less time in timeout like 500 and when the app is not installed in the iPhone, it should redirect to given app store link.
I have the correct `apple-app-site-association` file and correct GET API `/apple-app-site-association`.

Please suggest any solution. There are a lot of questions on the StackOverflow but no one is working for me.

**Technologies:** Nodejs, iOS, Hapijs, Javascript, Html.

**Browser:** Safari ( in iPhone )

Comment: I've implemented deep link many times , and I've to say I do use 5000 ms for delay 500ms is very less , as user need to perform action on popup in safari to open app if it is there,so basically you have to play with delay time, also you can try universal deep links

Comment: Only call this code line 'window.location.href = document.body.getAttribute('appstorelink');' when Deeplink failed to detect app. Not call this in setTimeout function.